# PHP calculate sum of elements

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm looking form simple algoritm, to calculate, from array:

```
 $condition = array(2, 20, 200);
```

to:

```
 $condition = array(2, 20, 200, 22, 202, 220, 222);
```

Can someone tell something simpler than:

```
        if(!empty($condition))
        {
            $a = 1;
            $condition_temp = array();              

            foreach($condition as $c1)
            {
                $c2 =array_slice($condition, $a++);
                foreach($c2 as $c3)
                {
                    $condition_temp[] = $c1 + $c3;      
                }
            }

            $condition_temp[] = array_sum($condition);
            $condition = array_merge($condition, $condition_temp);              
        }
```

Order of result array is not important.
thx for help :)

Comment: You want to sum integers in an array ?

Comment: yes, sum of elements peer (2+20, 2+200, 20+200, 200+2, 2+20+200)

Comment: Are all values unique, and is each value composed only of 0 and 2 as in your question ?

Comment: I have only 2 posible arrays: 
1,10,100,1000... or
2,20,200,2000...

Answer (score 0):

It depends... you can do in in `O(n)` using more memory to store sub-sums or you can do in in `O(n^2)` using more time and less memory. It depends on how many numbers do you have and how quickly you need to compute sums.